# Hi I am new to COBOl. Im having trouble displaying my headers and footers. I have read the book and looked online and have had no progress

Tags: header, footer, cobol

Cobol program:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                          
PROGRAM-ID.    PROG-TWO.                          
AUTHOR.        MARKIED JONES.                     


FD  PATRON-LIST.                                  
01  PATRON-LINE        PIC X(80).                 



ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                             

 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                             
 FILE-CONTROL.                                     
    SELECT PATRON-FILE ASSIGN TO INFILE.         
    SELECT PATRON-LIST ASSIGN TO OUTFILE.        

 DATA DIVISION.                                    


 FILE SECTION.                                     
 FD  PATRON-FILE.                                  
 01  PATRON-RECORD.                                
     03 PR-NAME               PIC X(18).           
     03 PR-ADDRESS            PIC X(18).           
     03 PR-CITY-STATE-ZIP     PIC X(24).           
     03 PR-TARGET-CONTR       PIC 9(4).            
     03 PR-ACTUAL-CONTR       PIC 9(4).            
     03 PR-CONTR-DATE.                             
       05 PR-CONTR-MONTH      PIC XX.              
       05 PR-CONTR-DAY        PIC XX.              
       05 PR-CONTR-YEAR       PIC XX.              
     03 FILLER                PIC X(6).                      
 FD PATRON-LIST.                                             
 01 PATRON-LINE.                                             
     03 FILLER                PIC X.                         
     03 PL-NAME               PIC X(18).                     
     03 FILLER                PIC X.                         
     03 PL-ADDRESS            PIC X(18).                     
     03 FILLER                PIC XX.                        
     03 PL-CITY-STATE-ZIP     PIC X(24).                     
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                    


 01 WS-PATRON-LINE            PIC X(80).                     

 01 WS-HEADER-LINE-1.                                        

     03 FILLER                PIC X(18) VALUE SPACES.        
     03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "INDIANA".     
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.         
     03 FILLER                PIC X(10) VALUE "UNIVERSITY".  
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.         
     03 FILLER                PIC X(2)  VALUE "OF".          
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.         
     03 FILLER                PIC X(12) VALUE "PENNSYLVANIA".

 01 WS-HEADER-LINE-1-UL.                                     

     03 FILLER                PIC X(18) VALUE SPACES.        
     03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "-".           
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.         
     03 FILLER                PIC X(10) VALUE "-".           
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.         
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE "-".           
     03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.         
     03 FILLER                PIC X(12) VALUE "-".           
 01 HEADER-LINE-2.   
 03 FILLER                PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.                                   
    03 FILLER                PIC X(8)  VALUE "COMPUTER".  
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "SCIENCE".   
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(10) VALUE "DEPARTMENT".
01 HEADER-LINE-2-UL.                                      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(8)  VALUE ALL"-".      
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE ALL"=".      
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(10) VALUE ALL"-".      
01 HEADER-LINE-3.                                         
    03 FILLER                PIC X(22) VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "LISTING".   
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(2)  VALUE "OF".        
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "PATRONS".   
01 HEADER-LINE-3-UL.                                      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(22) VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "-".         
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(2)  VALUE "-".         
    03 FILLER                PIC X     VALUE SPACE.       
    03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "-".         
01  WS-COLUMN-HEADER-1.                                   
    03 FILLER                PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(6)  VALUE "PATRON".    
    03 FILLER                PIC X(8)  VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(6)  VALUE "PATRON".    
    03 FILLER                PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(6)  VALUE "PATRON".    
01  WS-COLUMN-HEADER-1UL.                                 
    03 FILLER                PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.      
    03 FILLER                PIC X(6)  VALUE "-".         
    03 FILLER                PIC X(8)  VALUE SPACES.      
     03 FILLER                PIC X(6)  VALUE "-".                
     03 FILLER                PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(6)  VALUE "-".                
 01  WS-COLUMN-HEADER-2.                                          
     03 FILLER                PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(4)  VALUE "NAME".             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(8)  VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "ADDRESS".          
     03 FILLER                PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(14) VALUE "CITY-STATE-ZIP".   
 01  WS-COLUMN-HEADER-2UL.                                        
     03 FILLER                PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(4)  VALUE "-".                
     03 FILLER                PIC X(8)  VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(7)  VALUE "-".                
     03 FILLER                PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.             
     03 FILLER                PIC X(14) VALUE "-".                
 01  WS-FOOTER-LINE-1.                                            
     03 FILLER                PIC X(24) VALUE                     
                               "TOTAL # OF PATRONS:".             
     03 WS-NUM-PATRONS        PIC Z9.                             
 01  WS-FOOTER-LINE-2.                                            
     03 FILLER                PIC X(32) VALUE                     
                               "PROGRAMMED BY A COSC 220 STUDENT".



  01 WS-EOF-SWITCH             PIC X(3).                          
  PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                             
  000-PRINT-PATRON-LIST.                                          

      OPEN INPUT PATRON-FILE                                      

          OUTPUT PATRON-LIST                     
     MOVE "NO" TO WS-EOF-SWITCH                  
     READ PATRON-FILE                            
          AT END MOVE "YES" TO WS-EOF-SWITCH     
     END-READ                                    
     PERFORM 100-PROCESS-PATRON-RECORD           
         UNTIL WS-EOF-SWITCH IS EQUAL TO "YES"   
     CLOSE PATRON-FILE PATRON-LIST               
     STOP RUN                                    
     .                                           

 100-PROCESS-PATRON-RECORD.                      
      MOVE PR-NAME TO PL-NAME                    
      MOVE PR-ADDRESS TO PL-ADDRESS              
      MOVE PR-CITY-STATE-ZIP TO PL-CITY-STATE-ZIP
      WRITE PATRON-LINE                          
      READ  PATRON-FILE                          
        AT END MOVE "YES" TO WS-EOF-SWITCH       
      END-READ                                   
      .                                          

  200-PRINT-PATRON-LINE.
```

Comment: Which book did you read???

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem, you just do

```
  write PATRON-LINE from  WS-HEADER-LINE-1
  write PATRON-LINE from  WS-HEADER-LINE-1-UL
  ...
```

personally I would put the page printing code in a procedure by itself (and check the line number)

```
  r0900-Page-header.

     if  line-number > ...
         write PATRON-LINE from  WS-HEADER-LINE-1
                           after advancing page
         ...
         move ...              to line-number
     end-if  
     .
```

Also look at [advancing clause](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=cobol%20after%20advancing%20page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=FS_vV9mwKMru8web9ZyIAg)

Comment: I just tried the snippet of code you suggested:                                    200-PRINT-PATRON-LINE.                                    write PATRON-LINE from  WS-HEADER-LINE-1
  write PATRON-LINE from  WS-HEADER-LINE-1-UL ........And it still just displays my output with out the headers or footers.

Comment: can you update the code in the Question. Also where did you call the new procedures from ???

Answer (score 0):

You Can use seperate para to write all the headers one after another once output file is opened. Do not forget to initialize the PATRON-LINE after moving and writing each single header.

Comment: I am very new to cobol. Could you write an example of what you are describing?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have opened Output file. Add below perform statement.

PERFORM 050-WRITE-HEADER.

050-WRITE-HEADER.
INITIALIZE PATRON-LINE
MOVE WS-HEADER-LINE-1 TO PATRON-LINE
WRITE PATRON-LINE

INITIALIZE PATRON-LINE
MOVE WS-HEADER-LINE-1-UL TO PATRON-LINE
WRITE PATRON-LINE

same for header 2 and 3.

Comment: INITIALIZE, the MOVE to the same field? Don't you trust computers? Please note, this is not a "forum". You don't make an answer for every comment, just to get around not being able to make a comment until you have 50 reputation points.

Comment: Also, outputting headings when they are not needed is very sloppy (althogh very common). What if you write no output lines (nothing meets the conditions)? You still get the heading, but just the heading.